# attempting to reference a deleted function because of inter dependency between classes

Tags: c++

I am getting `attempting to reference a deleted function` error which I feel is because of inter dependency between classes.

`Location.h`

```
#ifndef A_LOCATION_H
#define A_LOCATION_H

struct location {
    double lat;
    double lon;
    double alt;
};

#endif //A_LOCATION_H
```

`P.h`

```
#ifndef A_P_H
#define A_P_H

#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>

#include "Location.h"

class C;

class P {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<C>> C_List;
    struct location loc {};

public:
    P() = default;
    ~P() = default;

    std::mutex mut;

    void add_child(const std::string& th_name);
    void del();
    void set_data(double lat, double lon, double alt);

    struct location get_data();
};

#endif //A_P_H
```

`P.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

#include "C.h"    
#include "P.h"

void P::add_child(const std::string& th_name) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);

    auto& ref = C_List.emplace_back(std::make_shared<C>());
    ref->set_name(th_name);
    ref->set_P(this);
    ref->start();
}

void P::del() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);

    for (auto& c : C_List)
        c->terminate = true;

    for (auto& c : C_List)
        c->wait();

    C_List.clear();
}

struct location P::get_data() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);

    return loc;
}

void P::set_data(double lat, double lon, double alt) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);

    loc.lat = lat;
    loc.lon = lon;
    loc.alt = alt;
}
```

`C.h`

```
#ifndef A_C_H
#define A_C_H

#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

class P;

class C {
    P *p {};
    std::string name {};
    std::thread th {};
    struct location loc {};

    void run();

public:
    C() = default;
    ~C() = default;

    void set_P(P* p);
    void set_name(const std::string& name);
    void start();
    void wait();

    std::atomic<bool> terminate {false};
};

#endif //A_C_H
```

`C.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

#include "P.h"
#include "C.h"

void C::run() {
    while (!terminate) {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
        {
            auto loc = p->get_data();
            // perform calculation based on P's object location, and it's current location
        }
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}

void C::set_P(P* p) {
    this->p = p;
}

void C::set_name(const std::string& name) {
    this->name = name;
}

void C::start() {
    th = std::thread(&C::run, this);
}

void C::wait() {
    th.join();
}
```

`Main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

#include "P.h"

int main() {
    P p = P();

    p.add_child("C1");
    p.add_child("C2");
    p.add_child("C3");

    char input;
    std::cin >> input;

    p.del();
}
```

Also there exists a kind of deadlock that will happen when `del` function of `P's` object gets called. I am not getting how to resolve this issue?

This is the short description of the error I'm getting

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xmemory(671): error C2280: 'C::C(const C &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
C:\Users\HARSHA\Desktop\LC\2022\A\C.h(33): note: compiler has generated 'C::C' here
C:\Users\HARSHA\Desktop\LC\2022\A\C.h(33): note: 'C::C(const C &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\thread(93): note: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)': function was explicitly deleted
```

Comment: Fyi, `P p = P();` is  redundant. `P p;` . This ain't Java or C#.

Comment: `C` is non-copyable due to the `std::thread` member, you therefore need to be careful to avoid any operation on `C_List` that would require copying

Comment: You create a `vector<C>`, the elements of which must be able to be copied. But `C` contains a `thread`, which cannot be copied. You can create your own copy constructors and copy assignment operators for C to handle that case. They could, e.g., theoretically start a new thread. But that would be probably inefficient for frequent copies and destructions. Consider using a different container than `vector`, which gives you better control, and never copies elements.

Comment: @Sebastian there is no requirement for vector elements to be copyable (unless you can an operation on the vector which requires copying)

Comment: @AlanBirtles shall I make `CList` as `std::vector<C*>`?

Comment: My rule for headers is: If you don't need to include it, don't include it. In your case in `P.h` and `C.h` include each other resulting in possible issues with the include order. In `C.h` `#include "P.h"` should be removed, since the forward declaration of `P` is sufficient. Add this include in `C.cpp` instead.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ok, that requirement was only fixed until C++11, now it is operation specific https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: You're not using random-access in that container of Cs. You could just use a `std::list<C>`.

Comment: Also note that `std::atomic<bool> terminate {};` does not initialize the value of the atomic; you need to use `std::atomic_init` for this or simply provide the initila value `std::atomic<bool> terminate { false };` The presence of the atomic makes `C` neither moveable nor copyable which is required for use as template parameter of  `std::vector`. You could replace the template parameter with `std::unique_ptr<C>` to fix this.This would also make using a forward declaration for `C` in `P.h` sufficient as long as you implement the constructor/destructor of `P` in `P.cpp`(you can `= default` them)

Comment: @fabian I made changes based on yours suggestions, but still not getting compiled. Please find my updated post.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable either, so your change doesn't do any good.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Then I think I need to make use of normal pointer instead of smart pointer. Am I correct?

Comment: Works for me: You of course need to initialize the `std::unique_ptr`; otherwise you're dereferencing a null pointer: https://godbolt.org/z/EqrbTbYes The defaulting needs to be done in the cpp file though: `class P { ...  P(); ~P(); ...};` P.cpp: `P::P() = default; P::~P() = default;`

Comment: To improve performance you should terminate in `p::del()` by looping twice. One to set the flag and one to `wait()` which amounts to `join()`. That way the threads terminate in parallel not sequence. I'm not sure that's your 'kind of deadlock' but it will feel very slow because you're waiting per thread.

Comment: @Persixty Imagine `del` method is called which acquires `lock` and waits for threads to `join`. Now If one of the thread tries to acquire same `lock` inside `run` method after main thread has acquired `lock` inside `del` method..

Comment: @fabian looks like in MSVC `std::vector::emplace_back` doesn't return reference to the element added, have to use `back` member function to get reference to it after adding using `emplace_back`. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Harry Ahhh. Yes! "//perform calculation based on P's object location" and `get_data()` acquires the same lock. So the missing code will deadlock with `del()`. One answer here is a shared lock. Because `del()` doesn't need an exclusive lock until all the threads have terminated. Also the individual threads may be competing for the single `P::mut` member.

Comment: A normal pointer is dangerous, but you can freely use a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @fabian Can you please explain why the defaulting needs to be done in `P.cpp` file only?

Comment: @Harry The constructor/destructor needs access to the definition of `C` because of the vector. If you default it in the class itself, it's an inline constructor/destructor and cannot be used without knowing about `C`'s definition. If the constructor isn't inlined though, this works, since only the translation unit containing the constructor/destructor definition requires access to the definition of `C`.

Answer (score 0):

std::thread, std::atomic, std::mutex types are not copyable, so the compiler cannot produce the default copy-constructors and copy-asignments.

You must write your own copy constructors for C and P classes.

```
P(P const& arg){ ... do stuff ... }
```